# Not able to get value of textarea in .val

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<textarea cols="50" rows="5" id="txtHtmlContent">
</textarea>
```

jQuery:

```
if ( $("#rdbHtmlContent").attr("checked") ) {
  alert( $('#txtHtmlContent').val() );
}
```

But alert show empty. What is my mistake?

Comment: Is your `textarea` empty when you run this?

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson Nop textarea  is not empty.Thanks.

Comment: Also, is your textarea inside a form element?

Comment: @ShreeKhanal We'll need to see more code to better assist you.

Comment: Ya when i take`<input id="txtHtmlContent" type="text" />` its return a result but `textarea` is unable to return value. (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code seems to be working as expected. I setup a test case on jsbin and confirmed that it's working:

HTML

```
<input type="radio" id="rdbHtmlContent" checked /><br/>
<textarea cols="50" rows="5" id="txtHtmlContent">Foo</textarea>
```

JS/jQuery

```
if ( $("#rdbHtmlContent").attr("checked") )
  alert( $("#txtHtmlContent").val() );
```

Demo online: http://jsbin.com/iritid/2/edit

Comment: Thanks a lot.Its seems like browser problem.Its work.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Since the contents are not actually set as a value, you might get more consistent cross-browser behaviour by grabbing it with .html() or .text() instead of .val().